# How to manually save a reference object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Edit: Main problem was that when I added the reference fields, I did theater:reference and not theater:references so the field was not marked as a foreign key. Once I undid those migrations and redid them correctly, I was able to make this work.

In my showtimes controller, I am trying to automatically set the theater id to whatever theater owns the screen that the user inputed, but when I try to save it as an integer or a string, I get an error. Yet, when I try to save it as a theater object, I get "Unpermitted parameter: theater" from the console and a "Theater must exist" error from the rails application.

showtimes_controller:

```
class ShowtimesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_theater, only: [:create, :edit]
  before_action :set_showtime, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /showtimes
  # GET /showtimes.json
  def index
    @showtimes = Showtime.all
  end

  # GET /showtimes/1
  # GET /showtimes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /showtimes/new
  def new
    @showtime = Showtime.new
  end

  # GET /showtimes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /showtimes
  # POST /showtimes.json
  def create

    @showtime = Showtime.new(showtime_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @showtime.save
        format.html { redirect_to @showtime, notice: 'Showtime was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @showtime }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @showtime.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /showtimes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /showtimes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @showtime.update(showtime_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @showtime, notice: 'Showtime was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @showtime }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @showtime.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /showtimes/1
  # DELETE /showtimes/1.json
  def destroy
    @showtime.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to showtimes_url, notice: 'Showtime was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_showtime
      @showtime = Showtime.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_theater
      screenInfo = Screen.where("id = ?", params[:showtime][:screen])
      params['showtime']['theater'] = Theater.find(screenInfo[0]['theater_id'])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def showtime_params
      params.require(:showtime).permit(:date, :time, :archived, :movie_id, :theater, :screen)
    end
end
```

showtimes model:

```
class Showtime < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :theater
end
```

Showtimes _form

```
<%= form_for(showtime) do |f| %>
  <% if showtime.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(showtime.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this showtime from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% showtime.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %>
    <%= f.time_select :time %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :archived %>
    <%= f.check_box :archived %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :movie_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :movie_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :screen %>
    <%= f.text_field :screen %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :theater, :value => "" %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error when trying to save as integer:

```
Theater(#70015922237640) expected, got Fixnum(#11723820)
```

Error when trying to save as string:

```
Theater(#70015868755420) expected, got String(#11739240)
```

Logs when trying to save as Theater object:

```
    Started POST "/showtimes" for IP at 2016-11-08 20:22:37 +0000
Processing by ShowtimesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nENPV5d6YRXdcx3H+Xa9ZypGtyFlaTg+zyENGB10TmW9OyWxLR9Dsl7nDoG9irq+3qApiNA2/oEqL5RZ0SXorA==", "showtime"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2016", "date(2i)"=>"11", "date(3i)"=>"8", "time(1i)"=>"2016", "time(2i)"=>"11", "time(3i)"=>"8", "time(4i)"=>"20", "time(5i)"=>"22", "archived"=>"0", "movie_id"=>"2", "screen"=>"1", "theater"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Showtime"}
  [1m[36mScreen Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "screens".* FROM "screens" WHERE (id = '1')[0m
  [1m[36mTheater Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "theaters".* FROM "theaters" WHERE "theaters"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: theater
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[36mMovie Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE "movies"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
  Rendering showtimes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered showtimes/_form.html.erb (13.6ms)
  Rendered showtimes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 323ms (Views: 86.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

How the hell do I save this parameter?

Comment: Why you have a theater instead of a theater_id?

Comment: `Unpermitted parameter: theater` this is an important thing to look out for and take into account... it means there's something missing from your `permit/require` line

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning your object to an instance variable, and assigning it before saving?

**On your before_action**

```
def set_theater
  @theather = ... # Code to find the theather
end
```

**On your create action**

```
def create
  @showtime = Showtime.new(showtime_params)
  @showtime.theather = @theather
  ... # Code to save and handle errors
end
```

Comment: I get a `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `theater_id`):` error using this. Not sure why because I'm serving the whole object

Comment: Are you using any debugging gems like byebug? It'd be cool to see if the `set_theather` method is working properly.

Comment: "ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError " that's interesting... can you give us more context for this error? look in your console-window or logfile (log/development.log) and find that error.... after it there should be a stacktrace (which is about 30-ish lines of filenames with numbers after them). Copy that and paste it into your original question. This stacktrace will show us exactly which line of code caused this error - which is a really solid help to us in figuring out what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured it out. Had to undo migrations where I did theater:reference instead of theater:references, so it wasn't marked as a foreign_key making this whole thing so much harder

Answer (score 0):

You use `theater` instead of `theater_id` in several places in your code, and you'll need to change it in all the places, in order for this to work.

Firstly - you can't select a `theater` in our form... html doesn't recognise a type of `theater`and will not pass one through - so your form needs to pass the `theater_id` instead (which will be an integer that it happily can deal with).

```
# eg here make sure it's a theater_id
<%= f.hidden_field :theater_id, :value => @theater.id %>
```

next - your require/permit is probably what's throwing some errors - you need that to be theater_id as well:

```
def showtime_params
  params.require(:showtime).permit(:date, :time, :archived, :movie_id, :theater_id, :screen)
end
```

Now you need to fetch the theater out, using the screen-info param - but also keep in mind that this might come through as nil some times (so a guard-clause is always good):

```
def set_theater
  if params[:showtime].present? && params[:showtime][:screen_id].present?
    screen_info = Screen.find(params[:showtime][:screen_id])
    @theater = Theater.find(screenInfo.theater_id)
  end
end
```

Note: I have updated naming-schemes to be rail-standard and removed the thing where you try to set the theatre in params as below:

```
params['showtime']['theater'] = Theater.find(screenInfo[0]['theater_id'])
```

I don't know what you're actually trying to do with this line of code, but whatever it is, params doesn't work that way - consider that params is "the set of things that were passed through to us from the user, and are then thrown away" - we don't use it to store new values that we create ion the controller. That's what `@variable`s are for

Can you explain more what you're trying to do and we'll figure out the right way to do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured it out. Had to undo migrations where I did theater:reference instead of theater:references, so it wasn't marked as a foreign_key making this whole thing so much harder